# Possible Breeze/EntityFramework bug when using .expand .orderby .take

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

Discovered this problem while working on a project at work, but have managed to replicate it using the DocCode sample from Breeze. I am using the latest 1.3.0. Basically the wrong records are being returned by the query when using 'expand', 'orderby' and 'take'. The problem can be demonstrated with the 'products sorted by related Category descending' test in queryTests.js:

The query in the test is:

```
    var query = EntityQuery.from("Products")
        .expand("Category")
        .orderBy("Category.CategoryName desc, ProductName");
```

Which causes the following SQL to be issued to SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
[Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
[Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
[Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
[Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
[Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
[Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
[Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
[Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
[Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued], 
[Extent2].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID1], 
[Extent2].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent2].[Picture] AS [Picture]
FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]
ORDER BY [Extent2].[CategoryName] DESC, [Extent1].[ProductName] ASC
```

Which is fine and gives the correct results sorted by CategoryName. However, if I change the query to the following:

```
    var query = EntityQuery.from("Products")
        .expand("Category")
        .orderBy("Category.CategoryName desc, ProductName").take(10);
```

I have added the '.take(10)'. The SQL becomes:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
[Limit1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
[Limit1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
[Limit1].[CategoryID1] AS [CategoryID], 
[Limit1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
[Limit1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
[Limit1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
[Limit1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
[Limit1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
[Limit1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued], 
[Extent3].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID1], 
[Extent3].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
[Extent3].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent3].[Picture] AS [Picture]
FROM   (SELECT TOP (@p__linq__0) [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName]\, [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID1], [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued], [Extent2].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[ProductID] ASC ) AS [Limit1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent3] ON [Limit1].[CategoryID1] = [Extent3].[CategoryID]
ORDER BY [Limit1].[CategoryName] DESC, [Limit1].[ProductName] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=10
```

Which is wrong because Extent1 is being ordered by ProductID instead of CategoryName which leads to the wrong records being returned.

So is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: As of v 1.3.2, this should be fixed.  Please post back here if you still see the problem.

---

Ok, I've just repro'd it and this is a bug.  Thanks for finding and reporting it. I'll try to get a fix out in the next release.  I will post back here when it gets in.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I should be able to test the update sometime next week.

Comment: I'm using v1.4 and still seeing this behavior in a similar scenario. I know this is a really old thread - hoping someone still see's it

Comment: Are you running the query shown above or something else?

Comment: I'm running something else - the issue seems to occur if orderBy column is a property of the items in the expand clause. If I orderBy something in the base query, it seems to work properly. The  only other difference between orderBy's that work and don't is the one I notice which doesn't work is an Integer column

Comment: BTW - I'm using Breeze Client v1.4.8

Comment: Please try 1.5.1 or the latest on GitHub which will be released next week as 1.5.2.